# iPhone App Receive Headset Button Presses While in Background

Tags: iphone, background

Is it possible for an iPhone app to receive headset button press events while in the background? Assuming this is an app with an UIBackgroundModes of audio.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with iOS 4.

`[UIApplication beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents]`